# On what basis to decide whether to use Aura component or LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura

what are the task that can be done in aura but not in lightning web component  and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use LWC unless a feature is not supported. In the interest of creating a future-proof answer, I will not provide any specific restrictions here, as this list is quickly being whittled down release after release. You need to consult the documentation and/or Release Notes to see if a given feature is supported or not. Your general development process should be something like this:

- Assume you can use LWC
- Check Documentation to see if a feature doesn't exist
- If a feature doesn't exist, fall back to Aura

You should never use Aura, if possible, as it simply doesn't perform as well as LWC, and virtually all tasks in Aura are written much more concisely in LWC; LWC saves you both development time and your users' perception of performance. Your default position should be to assume that LWC is the path you want to take. Only after consulting the documentation, if you find a given task is impossible, then write it in Aura.

Comment: thank you @sfdcfox for the explanation.

Comment: Just to add to this, our approach is to always use LWC; and if we HAVE to use Aura (like in VF or in quick action until Summer 21) we will create a wrapper Aura that then hosts the LWC. So all of OUR code and logic is always in LWC.

Comment: @zaitsman That's a good point. As far as I'm aware, you can *always* wrap a LWC in Aura to get around the limitations.